# HTML Button on top of image doesn't stay fixed when browser window is resized

Tags: html, css

I've learned how to put an html form element on top of an image. Now I want the button to stay when I resize the window.

Please look here:

http://derbuttle.com/test/easing.html

PS: I know this question is very banal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not banal. This may seem trivial but it trips people up all of the time if they don't do it a lot. I guess it depends on how you are placing the form on top of the image.

- Are you making the image be the background of the Form?
- Are you using css absolute or relative positioning?
- Are you using javascript/jquery to position the element.

One important aspect of what you are doing is to be aware that by placing on element on top of another you are going to need to ensure that it has been removed from the flow of the document, usually by using 
a `position:absolute;` or `position:relative;` rule in your css. Once you do this, the element will be positioned absolutely or relatively with respect to the lowest non-statically positioned element that contains it. If you run the snippet I've included you'll see that you can click anywhere inside the red div and all of the elements move to where you clicked but retain their relationship to each other.

I hope this answers your question.

```js
var add = 20;
var leftCt = $("div#left_ct");
var cnt = $('div#container');
var bkg = $('div#background_relative');

cnt.on("click", function(e) {
  var left = e.pageX - cnt.position().left - 10;
  var top = e.pageY - cnt.position().top - 30;
  bkg.css({
    left: left,
    top: top
  });
  leftCt.html(left);
})
```

```css
div#container {
  padding:10px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: salmon;
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
}
div#background_relative {
  display: block;
  margin: 10px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
div#background_relative>* {
  left: 0;
  background-color: lightblue;
  position: absolute;
}
img {
  top: 20px;
}
form#form_over_image {
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index: 1;
  left: 10%;
  top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='left_ct'></div>
<div id='container'>
  Container has position:relative
  <div id='background_relative'>
    Background has position:relative
    <img src='' alt='image has position:absolute' width=200 height=200 />
    <form id='form_over_image'>
      <div>form has position: absolute</div>
      <input type='text' value='' />
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your positioning the button using absolute positioning relative to the entire window, rather than it's containing div. Since you're using an image as the background/layout in your example, it would be near impossible to achieve what you're looking to do.

See this for further details: http://learnlayout.com/position.html